# access fortran module data from c using gfortran and gcc

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to access module variables in a fortran code, calling it from C. I already call a subroutine, but cannot call the variables.

```
module myModule
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
real(C_FLOAT) aa(3)
contains
subroutine fortranFunction() bind(C)

print *,"hello world from Fortran 90"
aa(1)=1.0;
aa(2)=2.0;
aa(3)=3.0;

end subroutine

end module
```

and the C code is

```
#include "stdio.h"

extern void fortranfunction();
extern float mymodule_aa_[3];

int main()
{
printf("hello world from C\n");
fortranfunction();

printf("%f %f %f \n",aa[0],aa[1],aa[2]);
return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling via

```
gcc -c ccode.c
gfortran -c fortrancode.f90
gcc fortrancode.o ccode.o -lgfortran -o myprogram
```

to which the gcc responds with undefined reference to `aa'

Comment: How is `aa` being passed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using objdump to look at the symbols, we see

```
0000000000000000 g     O .bss   000000000000000c __mymodule_MOD_aa
```

You need to add `bind(C)` to your aa variable

```
module myModule
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
real(C_FLOAT), bind(C) :: aa(3)
contains
subroutine fortranFunction() bind(C)

print *,"hello world from Fortran 90"
aa(1)=1.0;
aa(2)=2.0;
aa(3)=3.0;

end subroutine

end module
```

now `$ objdump -t fortrancode.o` says

```
000000000000000c       O *COM*  0000000000000004 aa
```

and

```
#include "stdio.h"

extern void fortranfunction();
extern float aa[3];

int main()
{
printf("hello world from C\n");
fortranfunction();

printf("%f %f %f \n",aa[0],aa[1],aa[2]);
return 0;
}
```

and

```
$ ./myprogram 
hello world from C
 hello world from Fortran 90
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
```